# Problem with Header File Not Being Sensed in Compilation

Tags: ros, catkin-make, compilation, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am having issues compiling a simple package that I built. In the end, after compilation I am getting an error:

```
make[2]: *** [robbie_tf/CMakeFiles/robbie_tf_node.dir/src/robbie_tf_node.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [robbie_tf/CMakeFiles/robbie_tf_node.dir/all] Error 2
```

But, earlier in the compilation, I am getting an error:

```
/home/jmcunnin/catkin_ws/src/robbie_tf/src/robbie_tf_node.cpp:28:38: fatal error: robbie_tf/robbie_tf_node.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

The package that I am compiling is named robbie_tf and the header file that is not being used is the header for the node file (kind of an issue :P). Any help would be appreciated.

Also, this is my CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

project(robbie_tf)


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
people_msgs
roscpp
rospy
std_msgs
tf
)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread)

catkin_package(
 INCLUDE_DIRS include
 LIBRARIES robbie_tf
)


include_directories(
   ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(robbie_tf_node
   src/robbie_tf_node.cpp
 )


 add_executable(robbie_tf src/robbie_tf_node.cpp)


add_dependencies(robbie_tf_node robbie_tf_generate_messages_cpp)


target_link_libraries(robbie_tf
  robbie_tf_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
 )
```

I would assume that the issue lies in the CMakeList but I'm not sure where my declarations are going wrong.

Thanks, for the help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188387/problem-with-header-file-not-being-sensed-in-compilation/) by [jc2016](https://answers.ros.org/users/19388/jc2016/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2014-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to add the include folder of your package to the include_directories() call:

```
include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

Your CMake file also lacks some install rules to install your headers and artifacts (but that is a different topic).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jc2016](https://answers.ros.org/users/19388/jc2016/) on 2014-07-31**:
This ended up working out. Thanks for the pointer.

**Comment by [jc2016](https://answers.ros.org/users/19388/jc2016/) on 2014-07-31**:
Also, do you happen to know if there are any resources where I can read up on headers and artifacts?